# Migrate tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization to Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

I want to migrate a github Project https://github.com/liupei101/TFDeepSurv von TF1 to TF2, because of other dependecies.
The Problem file by converting with the tf_upgrade_v2 skript is https://github.com/liupei101/TFDeepSurv/blob/master/tfdeepsurv/dsl.py.
This lines cannot be convert

```
reg_item =tf.contrib.layers.l1_l2_regularize(self.config["L1_reg"], self.config["L2_reg"])
loss_reg = tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(reg_item, tf.compat.v1.get_collection("var_weight"))
```

For the first one, I think the corretly migration is:

`reg_item = tf.keras.regularizers.L1L2(l1=self.config["L1_reg"], l2=self.config["L2_reg"])`

Which one are the right replacements for those 2 lines?

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow 2.x, keras training loops helps us to apply regularization, activation losses automatically, no need to call explicit `apply_regularization` method. For more information take a look at [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#use_keras_training_loops)
Use `tf.keras.regularizers.L1L2` in TF v2.x